# Highcharts basic bar

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to use export api of the highcharts with the bar type.

Do you know if I can define different number of bars for each group?

I will try to explain on an example, take http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic can I remove year 1900 from Asia and add year 1700 to America? Without showing zeroes in other groups.

Comment: I didn't understand your question, you can add `null` as value to prevent to show. `Year 1800` is already on `America`.

Comment: Yes I now tried try 'null' in jsfiddle and it worked, thank you ! I was trying to convert python lists with None and it wasn't working. I have to manually add 'null' as a string to python array and it will probably do the job.